# Misleading contact form text about scrapers?

Tags: support

A [scraper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) is a web site that duplicates Stack Overflow content and presents it. From the link:

> ### When should I report these sites?
>
> **The site is a proxy**. Whatever the purpose of the site actually is, malicious or not, proxies represent a serious security threat to our
>   site. Sometimes they even start showing up in Google results and users
>   click on them not realizing that they aren't actually on Stack
>   Overflow. Users get confused, or try to log in and accidentally send
>   sensitive information to a third-party service.

The text on the [report page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) says:

> Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution

Consider this:

https://codedump.io/share/0WR8RFaJeeKD/1/swift---get-device39s-ip-address

and the original SO content:

[Swift - Get device's IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-ip-address)

The scraper is a proxy, but has proper attribution. The meta SO question about scrapers sounds like proxies should be reported as well. However, the text on report link does not make it clear if proxies should be reported if they have proper attribution.

So, should I report this scraper or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the fact that there is another definition for *proxy*, which in this context means a website that exactly mimics ours. In essence, it's showing you *our pages* under *their URL* by simply rewriting your original request to our server and then displaying the result we send to them, to you. That is not exactly the same as a scraper, and due to the way proxies in general work, they represent a security threat to our users.

The scraper you identified is not a proxy in any sense of the word. It is just a simple scraper, which generally downloads the data in some way into their own database and displays the content using their own themes, layouts, and structure. If it has proper attribution, then there is no reason to report it because they're following the rules and there's nothing anyone can do about it.

Comment: Nevertheless, they must be stealing a significant amount of traffic, since they appeared on the first page of my Google search. Receiving traffic without any added value seems like not at all fair to me, but if that's how it works, then I guess there is nothing can be done about it.

Comment: We used to be able to report those instances to Google to at least get them to appear below us, but Google stopped accepting those reports and thus we stopped accepting them too (there's not a lot *we* can do about it ourselves, so it's mostly just useless information to us at this point).

Answer (score 0):

It say on the [legal notes](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

And this license allows you to share the content if you provide attribution to SE. So it look legitimate use of content from SO.

Comment: On the other hand, "Users get confused, or try to log in and accidentally send sensitive information to a third-party service.". So this seems like a reason to report as well. But I don't know.

Comment: Lets wait and see if my answer get more upvotes or downvotes - It would be a good indicator to whether I'm right or wrong. But as this site doesn't seem to impersonate SO design-wise, and they give a proper credit to SO then I think it's fine (Based on the Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported  license terms